# MongoDB Linking a $jsonSchema to another $jsonSchema

Tags: mongodb, jsonschema, ref

I have two schemas with 1 to N relation. one is book and the other author.

[image]

I have crated three files names: book.js, genre.js and author.js below. As you see, I have referenced in the book the genre and author from other files.

```
author: {
               $ref: "./models/author.js"
            },
```

and

```
"genre" : {
               $ref: "./models/genre.js",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
        }
```

However, When I issue that in mongo> i get the following:

```
{
"ok" : 0,
"errmsg" : "$jsonSchema keyword '$ref' is not currently supported",
"code" : 9,
"codeName" : "FailedToParse"
```

}

I was wondering How I could do that please?

```
// book.js
var book = {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "title", "author", "summary", "isbn", "genre" ],
         properties: {
            title: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            author: {
               $ref: "./models/author.js"
            },
            isbn: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 2017,
               maximum: 3017,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 2017, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            "summary" : {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            "genre" : {
               $ref: "./models/genre.js"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

module.exports = book;

//genre.js
var genre = {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "name"],
         properties: {
            first_name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               size: 100,
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            url: {
               bsonType: "string",
               minLength:3,
               maxLength:20,
               description: "must be a string and size between [3, 100] is not required"
            }
        }
      }
   }
};
module.exports = genre;

//author.js
var Author = {
   validator: {
      $jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "first_name", "family_name" ],
         properties: {
            first_name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               maxLength:100,
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            family_name: {
               bsonType: "string",
               maxLength:100,
               description: "must be a string and is not required"
            },
            date_of_birth: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 0,
               maximum: 2018,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 0, 3017 ] and is required"
            },
            date_of_death: {
               bsonType: "int",
               minimum: 0,
               maximum: 2018,
               exclusiveMaximum: false,
               description: "must be an integer in [ 0, 2018 ] and is required"
            }
         }
      }
   }
};
module.exports = Author;
```

It seems the Manual References does not work:

```
$jsonSchema: {
         bsonType: "object",
         required: [ "title", "author_id", "summary", "isbn", "genre" ],
         properties: {
            title: {
               bsonType: "string",
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            author_id: {
               bsonType: ObjectId(),
               description: "must be a string and is required"
            },
            isbn: {
```

as

```
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "$jsonSchema keyword 'bsonType' must be either a string or an array of strings",
    "code" : 14,
    "codeName" : "TypeMismatch"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "$jsonSchema keyword '$ref' is not currently supported",

As per the error message you encountered, the implementation of JSON Schema does not (as at MongoDB 4.0) support references (`$ref`). Since `$jsonSchema` is being validated on the database server a relative file path isn't appropriate; you should instead inline the required schema validation rules.

If you want more flexibility you could look for a validation library you can use in your application code. There are several JSON Schema packages on NPM as well as alternative approaches such as Object-Document Mappers (for example, [Mongoose](https://mongoosejs.com)).

> It seems the Manual References does not work
>
> ```
>      bsonType: ObjectId(),
> ```

The `ObjectId()` usage here isn't valid JSON. You need to specify a string value with the [BSON type](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/#document-type-available-types): `bsonType: "objectId"`.

For more information see `$jsonSchema` [Extensions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#extensions) and [Omissions](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/jsonSchema/#omissions) in the MongoDB documentation for your server version.

Comment: Are you talking about https://json-schema.org? I am using MongoDB in my node applications. I certainly do validation on application side for the forms or anything that make sense.

Comment: how come in terminal? > typeof ObjectId("5c036dd47d0db45bee0f64df") == 'object'
true
> typeof ObjectId("5c036dd47d0db45bee0f64df") == 'objectId'
false

Comment: @chikitin I'm referring to the implementation of `$jsonSchema` in MongoDB for extensions and omissions, and more generic JSON Schema support if you were looking for application validation using references on NPM. The `typeof` value for `ObjectId()` is expected to be an `object` because native JavaScript does not know about [MongoDB Extended JSON](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json) types. The `mongo` shell and extended JSON syntax provide helper functions to work with extended types where appropriate, but don't extend the built-in JavaScript types.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much. bsonType: "objectId". To be honest with you, I don't like using Mongoose. Using manual referencing:

```
original_author_id = ObjectId()
```

db.author.insert({
    "_id": original_author_id,
    first_name: "ghadamali",
    family_name: "sarami",
    date_of_birth: NumberInt(1944)
});
original_genre_id = ObjectId()

db.genre.insert({
    "_id": original_genre_id,
    name: "action",
    url: "www.action.com"
});

db.book.insert({

```
title:"az range gol",
author_id: original_author_id, 
summary: "shekle senasi shahname", 
isbn: NumberInt(12312), 
genre:original_genre_id
```

});